# answers Can I make my code shorter using loops?

Tags: c, cs50

*is there a way to make this code shorter?*

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int compute_score(string word);

```
            int main(void)
            {
                // Get input words from both players
                string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
                string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");
    
                // Score both words
                int score1 = compute_score(word1);
                int score2 = compute_score(word2);
    
                // TODO: Print the winner
                if (score1 > score2)
                {
                    printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
                }
                else if (score1 < score2)
                {
                    printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
    
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("Tie!\n");
                }
            }
```

*the calculator function*
*I Haved to definition character is uppercase or lower in different loops and i think i can make that in one loop but i don't know how :)*

```
 int compute_score(string word)
    {
            int points[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1,1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
            int len = strlen(word);
 

            int i = 0;
            int total = 0;
            for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)
            {
                if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
                {
                    int ascii = word[i];
                    int toasc = ascii - 65;
                    total += (points[toasc]);
                }
            }

            int ii = 0;
            int totall = 0;

            for (ii = 0; ii <= len; ii++)
            {
                if (word[ii] >= 97 && word[ii] <= 122)
                {
                    int asciii = word[ii];
                    int toascc = asciii - 97;
                    totall += (points[toascc]);
                }
            }
            int totalf = total + totall;
            return totalf;
        }
```

Comment: OT: `for (i = 0; i <= len; i++)` --> `for (i = 0; i < len; i++)`

Comment: Making code shorter should never be a goal by itself. Especially not if a "shorter code" is more complicated. However, in your case the code needs rewrite but the question should rather be "How do I avoid having two nearly identical code blocks". A common answer to that is: **Use a function.** In your case the two blocks only differ by 65 versus 97 and 90 versus 122. So you can make a `compute_score_range` which besides the string takes lower and upper limits as arguments. .....

Comment: cont.... Then you can simply call that function twice like `total_score = compute_score_range(word, 65, 90) + compute_score_range(word, 97, 122);`

Comment: That said, you shouldn't use those magic numbers. Instead of 65 use `'A'`. Instead of 90 use `'Z'` and so on....

Comment: To avoid accessing `points` out of bounds, it may be a good idea to only pass the lower limit to a function and calculate the upper limit from the number of elements in `points`. Could look like: https://ideone.com/LQNE8y

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like this:

```
int compute_score(string word) {
    int total = 0;
    int points[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1,1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
        if (word[i] >= 'A' && word[i] <= 'Z')
            total += points[word[i] - 'A'];
        else if (word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z')
            total += points[word[i] - 'a'];
    return total;
}
```

Comment: This communicates the intent more clearly.

Answer (score 3):

Normalizing the current letter to upper case which allows a fixed 'A' to be used to determine the offset into the points array.  Consider changing the type of `point` from `int` to `static const char []` for correctness.

```
#include "cs50.h"
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PLAYERS 2

int compute_score(string word) {
    int points[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1,1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    int total = 0;
    for (; *word; word++)
        total += isalpha(*word) ? points[toupper(*word) - 'A'] : 0;
    return total;
}

int main(void) {
    int scores[PLAYERS];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        scores[i] = compute_score(get_string("Player %d: ", i + 1));
    }

    // TBD: generalize print of winners
    static_assert(PLAYERS == 2);
    if (scores[0] > scores[1]) {
        printf("Player 1 wins!\n");
    } else if (scores[0] < scores[1]) {
        printf("Player 2 wins!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}
```

If you want to generalize the print of winners then it's more direct to just remember who the winners are as you go along.  For example:

```
#include <string.h>

// ...

int main(void) {
    int max_score = -1;
    char winners[PLAYERS];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        int score = compute_score(get_string("Player %d: ", i + 1));
        if(score > max_score)
            memset(winners, 0, sizeof(winners));
        if(score >= max_score)
            winners[i] = 1;
    }

    printf("Winner(s)");
    for(size_t i = 0; i < PLAYERS; i++) {
        if(winners[i]) printf(" %d", i + 1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You demonstrate that you know **strings** are **arrays** of characters (with a null terminator on the end).

The following uses a "purpose-built" array that stores the points of both upper and lowercase ASCII alphabet characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compute_score( string word ) {
    char tbl[] = { // small values fit into one byte
         0,  1,  3,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,  4,  1,  8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1,
         3, 10,  1,  1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  8,  4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0,  1,  3,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,  4,  1,  8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1,
         3, 10,  1,  1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  8,  4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };
    int points = 0;

    for( int i = 0; word[ i ]; i++ ) { // each letter of the word

        int c = word[i] - '@'; // transpose down to range 0-63

        if( 0 < c && c < 4*16 ) // if still in range...
            points += tbl[ c ]; // then retrieve point value of this letter
    }

    return points;
}

int main() { // A simple test program with a few words.

    string str;

    str = "Hello"; printf( "'%s' %2d pts\n", str, compute_score( str ) );
    str = "world"; printf( "'%s' %2d pts\n", str, compute_score( str ) );
    str = "quiz "; printf( "'%s' %2d pts\n", str, compute_score( str ) );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
'Hello'  8 pts
'world'  9 pts
'quiz ' 22 pts
```

**EDIT:** To use an even smaller "look-up table", invoke a little "modulo arithmetic"...

```
int compute_score( string word ) {
    // point values are arrayed correspondint to ASCII character positions
    uint8_t tbl[] = {
         0,  1,  3,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,  4,  1,  8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1,
         3, 10,  1,  1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  8,  4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };
    int points = 0;

    for( int i = 0; word[ i ]; i++ )
        if( word[ i ] >= 'A' )
            points += tbl[ word[ i ] % 32 ];

    return points;
}
```

**EDIT2:** Since we only want the look-up value for the upper two (alphabetic) ranges of the 7-bit ASCII table, AND C guarantees that the truth value of a condition will be either 0 (false) or 1 (true), the code could be made more contemporary using a "branchless programming" technique.

```
    for( int i = 0; word[ i ]; i++ )
            points += (word[i] >= 'A') * tbl[ word[ i ] % 32 ];
```

For other ASCII characters like digits or SP, the condition is false so no points are awarded. For characters in the right range, the points value is multiplied by 1 (the multiplication identity value).

Eventually, one's entire program can be reduced to a few lines... :-)

**EDIT3:** Now, turning attention to `main()` and its role in running the competition. Below combines (and renames) the function and its parameters.

The primary difference in this code is to recognise that each 'round' starts with zero. Subtracting the two players' scores
will give a positive number, zero, or a negative number.
Eliminating intermediary variables, each player gets a turn, their score computed, and the difference calculated all in one statement.
Then an appropriate message displayed.

Because this is fun, a `do/while()` loop offers the opportunity to play again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int score( string word ) {
    char pts = 0, tbl[] = {
         0,  1,  3,  3,  2,  1,  4,  2,  4,  1,  8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1,
         3, 10,  1,  1,  1,  1,  4,  4,  8,  4, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    };

    for( int i = 0; word[ i ]; i++ )
        pts += (word[i] > 'A') * tbl[ word[ i ] % 32 ];

    word[ i-1 ] = '\0'; // trim '\n' from end before printing

    printf( "'%s' - %d points\n", word, pts );

    return pts;
}

int main() {
    do {
        int diff
        = score( get_string( "Player 1: " ) )
        - score( get_string( "Player 2: " ) );

        if( diff > 0 )
            puts( "\nPlayer 1 wins!" );
        else if( diff < 0 )
            puts( "\nPlayer 2 wins!" );
        else
            puts( "\nTie!");

    } while( get_int( "\nPlay again? (0-yes otherwise ending)" ) == 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Player 1: house
'house' - 8 points
Player 2: car
'car' - 5 points

Player 1 wins!

Play again? (0-yes otherwise ending)0
Player 1:
```

**Alternative** `main()` using trenary "conditional operator":

```
int main() {
    do {
        int diff
        = score( get_string( "Player 1: " ) )
        - score( get_string( "Player 2: " ) );
        puts( diff > 0 ? "\nPlayer 1 wins!" : diff < 0 ? "\nPlayer 2 wins!" : "\nTie!" );
    } while( get_int( "\nPlay again? (0-yes otherwise ending)" ) == 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Neat.  What about about just doing a bitmask and shift then you could get rid of the if condition?

Comment: @AllanWind Can't "see" mask&shift. Plz sketch idea in comment. My preference would be _branchless_ and simply multiply truth of condition by table look-up value. Here come those cats, again, so anxious to be skinned... `:-)`

Comment: Too tired to be bit fiddling.  I was going for branchless like your 2nd solution so don't think it would be better than what you have.  It ain't shorter than my answer though so why am I tied for last place by score? :-)

Comment: @AllanWind "Score"?! I've spent 4hrs at "an answer" only to be rewarded with 0 points, and 5 min to earn 45 points... C'mon... Let's both admit we're here for the fun and jollies (and sometimes to witness the occasional shouting match...)  `:-)` We're in good company! Schrödinger had a thing for cats, too `:-)`

Comment: It was somewhat of an attempt at a pun given the question of winners and that we both were in "last" place with more interesting answers.  Concur, and I enjoy hanging with smart people.